# Swift equivalent to C# List

Tags: c#, json, swift2

I am a c# programmer and I am trying to build a native app using Swift 2.

```
public class ApiRoadsInfo
{

public string road_id { get; set; }
public List<RoadInfo> road_info { get; set; }
public List<Comment> comments { get; set; }

}
```

My question is: how do I create `List<>` like C# in Swift 2?

```
struct....{
var road_id:String
???????? how?
```

Comment: Please read the language guide. Don't write Swift-sharp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
let road_info: Array<RoadInfo> = Array<RoadInfo>()
```

or with the Swift shorthand:

```
let road_info = [RoadInfo]()
```

Please read the [language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#). It's quite concise and very well written. It'll introduce you to most of the basics you'll need to get started with Swift.

Comment: are you sure the second snippet compiles?

Comment: @luk2302 Forgot the `()`, fixed, Thanks.

Comment: No, not at all. This isn't C#. Read the language guide.

Comment: I was saying they have `{get; set;}` in their *original code*, of course. ;) And refering to your usage of `let` which, in my opinion, should be `var` to *reflect their own code, the `{get; set;}` I was referring to*. Sorry if I wasn't clear in my previous (deleted) comment.

Comment: Oh my bad, I mistook you for OP

Comment: Eh, no problem. Communication via comments is not easy. And I sometimes fail to make myself clear in English.